# Convert a iPython Notebook file, containing Latex, Markdown Texts and Graphs, to PDF

Tags: python, pdf, jupyter-notebook, pandoc, miktex

I am converting a ipython notebook file (mynotebook.ipynb) to a PDF file for model documentation. It contains some LaTex-format mathematical equations, markdown texts, codes and graphs.

For example, the ipython notebook file looks like this:

```
$$c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$$
TEXT: Companies must take risks if they are to survive and prosper.

import pandas as pd
%load_ext rmagic

%%R
plot(rnorm(1000))
```

I haven't got enough reputation to post the picture, so I hope you can understand how it looks like.

**I have installed the complete versions of MikTeX and Pandoc.**

I have tried several ways I found online:

***1.***

```
ipython nbconvert mynotebook.ipynb --to latex --post PDF
```

it gives me errors:

```
[NbConvertApp] Using existing profile dir: u'C:\\Users\\John Smith\\.ipython\\prof
ile_default'
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook mynotebook.ipynb to latex
[NbConvertApp] Support files will be in mynotebook_files\
[NbConvertApp] Loaded template latex_article.tplx
[NbConvertApp] Writing 13601 bytes to mynotebook.tex
[NbConvertApp] Building PDF: ['pdflatex', 'mynotebook.tex']
[NbConvertApp] CRITICAL | PDF conversion failed: ['pdflatex', 'mynotebook.tex']
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
("C:\Users\John Smith\Anaconda\mynotebook.tex"
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic,
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.11

?
! Emergency stop.
 ...

l.11

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on mynotebook.log.
```

***2.***

```
ipython nbconvert mynotebook.ipynb --to latex
pandoc mynotebook.tex -o mynotebook.pdf
```

Then the PDF file generated shows the markdown and latex formula perfectly; it shows graphs, but it doesn't show the R codes nicely.

***3.***

```
ipython nbconvert mynotebook.ipynb --to html
```

Then the html file shows the code, the markdown texts and the graph very well, but the latex formula is not shown in a good way.

===================================================

I didn't expect this difficulty, because everything looks so fancy in the ipython notebook when I edit them. iPython Notebook uses mathjax to show the formula, and shows other part perfectly too. But for some reason these techniques I have tried cannot convert all subjects into their proper formats.

I am wondering there is a solution with which I can convert all these things (markdown, code, graphs and LaTex Formula) to a PDF file nicely?

Comment: `ipython nbconvert mynotebook.ipynb --to latex --post PDF` should be all you need to do, can you try updating your IPython version?

Comment: @Marius Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I have tried this, and it gave me an error message. You can see it from my question. Or, do you mean this error is caused by my python version? I am using python 2.7.

Comment: Not your python version, your *ipython* version. The current version of ipython is 2.3, you should see what version you have in the first few lines of messages whenever you run an IPython console.

Comment: @Marius Thank you, Marius! I follow your suggestion and upgrade the iPython version, and it works perfectly. Many thanks!